# gstream with connection refused with local ip address

Tags: rtsp, ubuntu-20.04, gstreamer-1.0

```
ubuntu-20.04
```

Try to make gstream server with rtsp protocol

```
 gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! videorate ! jpegenc quality=30 ! tcpclientsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8554 -v
```

After proceed this command got following error

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTCPClientSink:tcpclientsink0: Could not open resource for reading.
Additional debug info:
gsttcpclientsink.c(366): gst_tcp_client_sink_start (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTCPClientSink:tcpclientsink0:
Failed to connect to host '127.0.0.1:8554': Connection refused
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```